# Laravel line by line debugging

Tags: laravel

am a newbie in laravel. When working out with samples most of the error shows message in a page called container.php. inorder to debug, using an extension that shows debugbar.would like to know is it possible to do line by line debugging in laravel and identify exact error of the code written in any way? Using visual studio code editor.

Comment: You can debug your code using [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has its own debugging system. you can use built in `dd()` function, And there are several packages that can be used to debug Laravel projects. Here are some links and hope that it will be helpful for you.

1. [02-04-2014-package-laravel-debugbar](https://laravel.io/forum/02-04-2014-package-laravel-debugbar)
2. [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **laravel-debugbar package**

[Laravel-DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

this  will show all the SQL query you are running all the route and all the errors just like **Chrome Developer Console**

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the entire sorted call stack and all details as arguments provided, function names, through the error page displayed. That error page is everything a programmer needs to understand what went wrong with the request and you will get used to it as soon as you fix an issue for the first time. Below I give some tips

[image]

Comment: Hi Matteus Barbosa, thanks.could you please see the screenshot posted below where the trace of error file seems to be not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Made an error on Provider folder file by appending '1' to the class filename on code.,
As the error is now on Provider file, it was expected to show that file in the stack trace.
Please see the screenshot attached where the error file is not shown, only laravel builtinfiles.